# Hibernate Criteria - how to limit join results to a single entity type?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

Ok, so the following query:

```
SELECT O.*, P.* FROM ORDERS O, PRODUCT P WHERE
    O.ORDER_ID=P.ORDER_ID AND P.ID=’1234’;
```

can be done with Criteria as follows:

```
List ordersAndProducts = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .setFetchMode(“products”,FetchMode.JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.eq(“id”,”1234”))
    .list();
```

but here `Criteria.list()` returns a `List<Object[]>` where `Object[0]` is an `Order` and `Object[1]` is a `Product` for each element in the List.

But how can I do the following SQL with Criteria:

```
SELECT O.* FROM ORDERS O, PRODUCT P WHERE 
    O.ORDER_ID=P.ORDER_ID AND P.ID=’1234’;
```

In other words, I want `Criteria.list()` to give me a `List<Order>`, I don't care about the `Products`. I've tried using `createAlias()` instead of `setFetchMode()` but the results are the same, and Projections don't let you specify an entity, only a property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` on the criteria.

```
List ordersAndProducts = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .setFetchMode(“products”,FetchMode.JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.eq(“id”,”1234”))
    .list();
```

Now you retrieve all orders with eagerly loaded products.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that using ResultTransformer would be the way, but the rather opaque documentation wasn't much help knowing which one to use.

Comment: nice answer (geht doch ... :-))

Comment: Where can I find more explanation about setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `createCriteria` method on the `Criteria` class for the relationship.

```
List ordersAndProducts = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .createCriteria(“products”)
        .add(Restrictions.eq(“id”,”1234”))
    .list();
```

You can read the (slightly confusing) documentation about it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations).

Comment: Nope, I already tried that, and it makes no difference, still get a List of Object arrays with both the Orders and the Products.

Comment: This should perform better, if you really don't care about the products(not calling the products later on). Look into your mapping or annotations. Did you instruct hibernate to eager load the products association via fetch. That could be the reason. I'm not quit sure but belief that the criteria API obeys this instruction.

Comment: The annotation I have in the Order class for the products is @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY). The only solution that works for me is yours above using ResultTransformer.