# Returning an Entity using Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

### [Hibernate] Returning an Entity using Criteria

Hi! Because of my poor English, I'll show directly my problem with examples.

I have two entities: Product and Category (one Product is associated with one Category). My problem is with this Criteria:

```
Criteria crit = createCriteria( Product.class, "prod" );  
crit.createAlias( "prod.category", "cate" );  
crit.add( Restrictions.eq( "cate.name", "TEST" ) );  
crit.add( Restrictions.eq( "prod.status", "ON" ) );  
List< Product > list = crit.list();
```

This returns, automatically, all attributes of **Product AND Category**, but I want **ONLY Product**. HQL works fine:

```
select prod 
from   Product prod join Category cate 
where  cate.nome = 'TEST' and prod.status = 'ON'
```

But I need this with Criteria! How it's possible?
Obs.: it's impracticable to use Projections since entities have around 30 attributes each one.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377249/hibernate-criteria-how-to-limit-join-results-to-a-single-entity-type

Answer (score 1):

Use `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer`:

```
crit.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using the fetch=eager or lazy=false property, Try to check the property values and change appropriately.

Comment: I'm using fetch=FetchType.EAGER on all associations.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding fetching mode for this criteria by adding

```
crit.setFetchMode("category", FetchMode.LAZY)
```